# navBar depend on width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navbar

I'm trying to make my website more mobile friendly and I want to make the navBar hide elements when the screen becomes too small in width. How would I go about doing this? I'm not very familiar with javascript so please explain what everything does in detail.

my website: http://www.mineglade.net/ 
currently kind of barren...

my current navBar looks like this:

```
    <header>
        <div class="navBar navCenter">
            <div class="navHome navElement">
                <a href="#home" class="homeButton">Home</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navStore navElement">
                <a href="#store" class="storeButton">Store</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navAbout navElement">
                <a href="#about" class="aboutButton">About</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navGallery navElement">
                <a href="#gallery" class="galleryButton">Gallery</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navContact navElement">
                <a href="#contact" class="contactButton">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

all relevant css styles:

```
html, body, main {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
    height: 100%;
}
a:link {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #222222;
    padding: 16px 16px 16px 16px;
    width: 72px;
}

a:visited {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #222222;
    padding: 16px 16px 16px 16px;
    width: 72px;
}

a:hover {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #4B4B4B;
    padding: 16px 16px 16px 16px;
    width: 72px;
}

a:clicked {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #222222;
    padding: 16px 16px 16px 16px;
    width: 72px;
}

.navBar {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    visibility: visible;
    background-color: #222222;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 999;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px;
}

.navCenter {
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
}

.navElement {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you need JavaScript? Have you heard about [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change CSS styles depending on screen resolution - use media queries! They are rather simple, I usually start with this list, then add new or delete existing queries if needed:

```css
/*==========  Desktop First Method  ==========*/

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {

}

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

}


/*==========  Mobile First Method  ==========*/

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {

}

 /* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {

}
```

Media queries are intuitive, but here are some info if you're totally new:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

*"I want to make the navBar hide elements when the screen becomes too small in width"*

Just choose media query (or define the new one) and write new rules inside this media query. If you want to hide element, when the screen width is less than 1200px for example, it should be something like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {
  #element-id {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: I've applied your example snippet in my css but my divs won't disappear when resizing my window, an image I've placed in the "about" section of my webpage does, however, disappear...

Comment: @MineGlade, if you're using frameworks, sometimes you need to use `!important` rule to override framework styles. Try to use `display: none !important;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide something based on screen size the best way to do it is with media queries. What you need to do is include something like this inyour css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 352px){
  #about {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

The above will take effect if the screen size is less than 352 px and hide the about section. Alternatively, there are also min-width media queries if you want to do something for a minimum screen size. The following will take effect if your screen size is greater than 352px

```
@media screen and (min-width: 352px){
  #about {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can by using @media attribute in CSS such as

```
@media (max-width:600px){
/* Items you want to hide or show by using display:none; for it */ 
}
```

so you can adjust every critical width and height of any screen from there, normally you just need 3 @media attributes:Small screens, Mid Screens, Tablets